# LUA.socket, HEADER

Tags: sockets, lua, header

Ive been browsing stackoverflow for years now for answers to my questions and this is the first time Im actually asking a question myself. Hopefully it wont be too vague.

Right now Im having some trouble understanding why my LUA code doesnt work. All I want to do is to request a connection and download the html file from the site. Here is the code

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

local response = {}
local body,code,headers,status = http.request({
    method = "GET",
    url = "http://jisho.org/",
    headers = {
        jap = "",
        eng = "hello",
        dict = "edict"
        },
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response)
    })
print(table.concat(response))
```

It is a simple code that should go into the dictionary website "jisho.org" and send the headers so it searches for the english word "hello" and print out the new pages html. Right now Im only getting the html for "jisho.org" and not the html from the site which has searched for "hello".

I am wondering what Ive done wrong?

Comment: Quick attempt on the website itself seems to show those are URL parameters not http headers. So sending them as headers isn't going to work. You need to stick them in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the website, you need to use a different URL and include query parameters in the URL itself (as suggested by Etan Reisner); the following code works for me:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
local response = {}
local body,code,headers,status = http.request({
    method = "GET",
    url = "http://jisho.org/words?jap=&eng=hello&dict=edict",
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response),
    })
print(table.concat(response))
```

I get back HTML with "Found words" section:

```
<!-- Found words -->
<div id="result">
    <div id="result_content">
...some HTML skipped...
            <td class="meanings_column">ahoy; hullo; hello          </td>
```

You can then parse the returned HTML to extract whatever values you need.